# Package-by-feature confusion for libraries

Tags: java, coding-style, project-structure, packages

As I understand it, it's generally recommended to package by feature rather than by layer. This promotes higher levels of abstraction and modularity between classes.

I can understand how this works in regular non-utility applications where it has clear features (`registration`, `security`, etc), but it is hard to apply this to static utility libraries.

For example, take a look [Google Guava's packaging structure](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava/src/com/google/common). As it is a library, it is hard to categorize the features of the library into packages. There is an `annotations` package, a `networking` package, etc. This feels like a bit of a grey-zone to me as it isn't packaged in an explicit format?

What is the general consensus when packaging by feature for something which consists of utility classes (such as a library/API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus probably does not exist. Logically, it makes no sense to follow the general consensus anyway. You should package according to the abstractions that make most sense for users of the library. If you are creating a low level library, the abstractions should be low-level.

The word "features" does not have much meaning in your question. Are they application-level features? If so, that might make sense for an application level library, but not for any other type of library.